# How to execute .sh file with php

Tags: php, linux, shell, sh, exec

Im trying to run a .sh File with shell_exec via php.

I tryed:

```
echo shell_exec('/path-to-file/bim2gaeb.sh');
```

i also tryed `exec()` but it doesnt work.

The .sh-File containts the command: `java -classpath /usr/share/java/xalan2.jar org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -xsl sra2gaeb.xsl -in BIM_Input.ifcxml -out GAEBGeruest.3.3.x83`

This script is supposed to create a .x83-File after a transformation via xalan.

execute the command manuelly via ssh worked fine, but if i try to run the script via php nothing happend.

Do someone have an idea how to run the script programmatically?

Comment: How is the php file being run ssh/web? Whats the full code of the .sh file?

Comment: Are you sure the jar is readable, the input is readable, and the output directory is writable, by the user PHP is running as?

Comment: You may need to add `sh` before the path to make sure it runs through the sh interpreter

Comment: Does the shell script begin with an appropriate `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: And also keep in mind that the process the php interpreter is executed under needs to be able to reach that script. So it needs read access to all folders up to that file. This often is not the case if the script is buried somewhere in a user home folder.

Comment: But most important: what error does your php process generate?

Comment: @D'AmestoxX : What exactly does _but it doesnt work_  mean? What happens if you run it as `shell_exec('sh -x /path-to-file/bim2gaeb.sh')`?

Comment: yes the .sh-File begins with #!/bin/sh, the files are readable and the output dir is writable too. With "it doesnt work" i mean that the script doesnt create the output-file